# Как добавить класс при наведении на блок в AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Есть несколько строк `<tr>`:

```
<tr class="list">
    <td class="buy">0/10</td>
    <td>
        <a class="buy-button">Купить</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Нужно чтобы по умолчанию подсвечивалась только первая (класс `buyButtonSelected`) строка, а при наведении на любую из строк - подсветка оставалась только у той, на которую навели в последний раз, при этом у всех остальных подсветку нужно убрать.

На jQuery это выглядело бы приблизительно так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content1 tr.list:nth-of-type(1) .buy-button').addClass('buyButtonSelected');
    $('#content1 tr.list').hover(function() {
        $('#content1 tr.list').removeClass('buyButtonSelected');
        $(this).addClass('buyButtonSelected');
    });
});
```

Проект написан на AngularJS и возможности использовать jQuery нет.
Есть ли подобный функционал в AngularJS? Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MainCtrl($scope) {
  
  $scope.values = [
    
    { buy: '0/10' }, 
    { buy: '0/20',selected: true }, 
    { buy: '0/30'}
    
  ];

  $scope.hoverIn = function() {
    this.hover = true;
    $scope.values.forEach(function(val) {
      val.selected = false;
    });

  };

  $scope.hoverOut = function() {
    this.hover = false;
  };

}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="value in values" ng-class="{'selected' : hover || value.selected}" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
    <td class="buy" ng-bind="value.buy"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

При помощи `ng-class` и `ng-mouseenter`: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/sytqcbaj/)**

**HTML:**

```
<tr class="list" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-mouseenter="selected.id = item.id">
    <td class="buy">{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="" class="buy-button" ng-class="{buyButtonSelected: selected.id === item.id}">Купить</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Контроллер:**

```
$scope.items = [
    {id: 1, name: 'товар 1'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'товар 2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'товар 3'}, 
    {id: 4, name: 'товар 4'},
    {id: 5, name: 'товар 5'}, 
    {id: 6, name: 'товар 6'}
];

$scope.selected = {id: 3};
```

Comment: Good example with stateful. I will take on note.

Answer (score 0):

В AngularJS есть частичная замена jQuery - [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngJq), возможностей которого достаточно для выполнения вашей задачи